# Headless browser capable of popup handling?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, phantomjs, headless-browser

I tried https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/ and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneChrome Docker images with browsers (first one is truly headless and the second one incorporates real chrome running under xvfb) and seems like both of them do no support javascript popups (via window.open) - because there is always only one element in driver.window_handles.

May be I should try it without docker, but any related info will be super appreciated.

I use python with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Selenium should handle this. You may paste what you have already done to check what is going on.

Comment: Why use a headless browser? Just use a regular browser and it will handle popups.